# Getting the number of stored elements of sparse matrix - Python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working with large sparse matrices in Python. The representation of my matrix gives me the number of stored elements, for example

```py
<100000x100000 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1244024860 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

My question is: **how do I get Python to return the number `1244024860` to me?** I want to use this number as an approximation to the number of nonzero elements (even though some of the stored elements could be zeros).

For smaller matrices I was using the `sparse_mat.count_nonzero()` method but this method actually does computations (I guess that it checks that the stored elements are actually different from zero) and therefore it is very inefficient for my large matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `nnz` attribute.  For example,

```
In [80]: a = csr_matrix([[0, 1, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3]])

In [81]: a
Out[81]: 
<3x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [82]: a.nnz
Out[82]: 3
```

The attributes of the `csr_matrix` class are described in the [`csr_matrix` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) (scroll down to find them).

Answer (score 1):

You ale looking for `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.getnnz`.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.getnnz.html

> Number of stored values, including explicit zeros.

Comment: Is there an advantage to using the method instead of the `nnz` attribute?

Comment: Likely not. I simply wasn't aware of underlying attribute being public and documented.

Comment: `A.getnnz( axis=1 )` gets the number of non-zeros per row, `A.getnnz( axis=0 )` per column, and `A.getnnz() == A.nnz`